# extracting typescript properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following:

```
interface Message {
  message?: {
    title?: string;
    description?: string;
    body?: string;
  };
}

const [message, setMessage] = useState<Message>({
    message: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      body: "",
    },
  });
```

and I'm trying to handle my form in this method where I fill the form with newly created values:

```
  const handleMessageInput = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    field: keyof Message
  ) => {
    setMessage({
      ...message,
      [field]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

 <input
            onChange={(e) => handleMessageInput(e, "title")}
            ref={(node) => {
              input = node;
            }}
          />

 <input
            onChange={(e) => handleMessageInput(e, "body")}
            ref={(node) => {
              input = node;
            }}
          />

 <input
            onChange={(e) => handleMessageInput(e, "description")}
            ref={(node) => {
              input = node;
            }}
          />
```

but the problem is when I submit the form I dont get my values means my state is not updated with the created values, which I think I missed something within extracting the fields, also is there a way to avoid using ref for each field I have ? so any help ?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey when create a state you defined it like this:

```js
useState<Message>({
    message: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      body: "",
    },
})
```

but then when you updating it you do like this:

```js
setMessage(
 {
   ...message,
   [field]: event.target.value
 }
)
```

See the difference? it supposed to be like this:

```js
setMessage(
 {
   message: {
     ...message.message,
     [field]: event.target.value
   }
 }
)
```

This way you will update the right thing, otherwise you are crating new fields near the `message` level of your object but you want to update the fields inside the `message` field in your object

EDIT:

To fix the error, you need to introduce a deep level type so when you say `keyof` it will refer to the right keys.

```js
  interface MessageFormValues {
    title?: string
    description?: string
    body?: string
  }

  interface Message {
    message: MessageFormValues
  }

  const handleMessageInput = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    field: keyof MessageFormValues,
  ) => {
    setMessage({
      message: {
        ...message.message,
        [field]: event.target.value,
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: The strange thing is that why TypeScript is not throwing any warnings at you.

Comment: thanks for the help, I didnt catched that, but we get another error after that which I added an update to it to my question, take a look pls

Comment: @A.H Hey I included the EDIT with the fix for this, you just remove `message` as a top level, because you don't really need this, and it will also fix your problem with this new error, let me know if it helps

Comment: hey, I cannot change the sctructure of my interface cause I have a specific type which I need to match for my backend ;). so this is kind of impossible now

Comment: Ok, let me suggest another option

Comment: So just by rewrite the deeper stracture as interface you are able to do `keyof MessageFormValues` and this will expect the right types, let me know if that will work for you :D

Comment: and now it worked! thanks dude ;) but another thing, do you have any idea how to avoid using ref in every input ? and make a generic one ?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting ref in the first place

Comment: ahh, I removed it, I created that code before but now I removed it ;) thanks again ;)